# Want to display the canvas image in my laravel project with in the @section tag

Tags: javascript, laravel-5, html5-canvas

I just want to display the canvas image in my laravel project.

I had already tried the canvas in separate files like Html and PHP files the canvas is working but when I am trying to show the canvas image in my laravel project total image is not displaying.

```
    @section('content-wrapper')
<canvas id="canvas" width="484" height="984"></canvas>
@endsection
            @push('scripts')
            <script src="https://www.marvinj.org/releases/marvinj-0.8.js"></script>
        <script>
            var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
            image1 = new MarvinImage();
            image1.load("packages/Webkul/Shop/src/Resources/assets/images/Group 1.png", imageLoaded);
            image2 = new MarvinImage();
            image2.load("packages/Webkul/Shop/src/Resources/assets/images/Rectangle 5.png", imageLoaded);
            image3 = new MarvinImage();
            image3.load("packages/Webkul/Shop/src/Resources/assets/images/Motif_2.png", imageLoaded);
            image4 = new MarvinImage();
            image4.load("packages/Webkul/Shop/src/Resources/assets/images/body_design_2.png", imageLoaded);

            var loaded=0;



            function imageLoaded(){
              if(++loaded == 4){
                var image = new MarvinImage(image1.getWidth(), image1.getHeight());
                Marvin.combineByAlpha(image1, image2, image, 43, 0);
                Marvin.combineByAlpha(image, image3, image, 0, 0);
                Marvin.combineByAlpha(image, image4, image, 50, 0);
                image.draw(canvas);
              }
            }

        </script>
        @endpush
```

Just want to display the canvas in my laravel project.